# Confluent Schema Registry vs Glue schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, schema, aws-glue, confluent-schema-registry

I am exploring on schema registries, I have a Kafka setup and now I want to introduce schema support for producer and consumer. I found that both are supporting Avro format and have multiple compatibility options. I am new to both. Can anybody suggest me which one is better or could compare them both.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: AWS glue does not provide any url endpoint for interacting with it, if you want to connect other tools to it: f eks kafkaui you cant, since it needs a schema-registry-url.

You are limited to using the aws sdk

Answer (score 2):

While Glue works with Kafka, from what I've seen, it is more intended for usage with Athena and similar AWS data-analysis tools. It is serverless, so there is nothing to install and manage, and integrates with IAM, so you can manage permissions all within AWS.

Confluent's is *only* for Kafka and cannot be (easily) integrated with those other AWS tools.